# conditionally render some items from React-Native FlatList

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am using the React Native FlatList like this:

```
export const UserList: React.FunctionComponent<UserListProps> = ({
  data,
  onSendRequest,
}) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={data?.users?.nodes}
        horizontal={false}
        scrollEnabled
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <User user={item} onSendRequest={onSendRequest} />
        )}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item?.id?.toString()}
        ListEmptyComponent={NoUsersContainer}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Currently, it renders all items. Is there any way I can introduce some sort of checks **inside** the Flatlist? For instance, if

`data.users.nodes.id == 1`

then don't render while all the rest should be rendered. Generally we could do something like this with a ternary operator or if-else statements but I couldn't think of a clean, correct way for FlatLists.

Comment: If you don't want to show nodes of a certain id, I would just filter the data to exclude those nodes before passing the data to the flatlist.

Answer (score 1):

Filtering your data seems like a good place to start. Assuming `data.users.nodes` is an array,

```
export const UserList: React.FunctionComponent<UserListProps> = ({
  data,
  onSendRequest,
}) => {
  const blacklist = [1, 3, 4]; // Node IDs to exclude
  const filteredNodes = data?.users?.nodes 
    ? data.users.nodes.filter(node => !blacklist.includes(node.id))
    : [];
  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={filteredNodes}
        horizontal={false}
        scrollEnabled
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <User user={item} onSendRequest={onSendRequest} />
        )}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item?.id?.toString()}
        ListEmptyComponent={NoUsersContainer}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```